# Vertical list of UILabels and NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have a vertical list of `UILabel`s:

[image]

I want to be able to have all the labels line up with the ":" on the right side and keep the spacing to the left side of the superView (createDate label stay put, and the name and year labels would shift to the right).

Code:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[nameLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[headerView]-[nameLabel]-[createDateLabel]-[yearLabel]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView, nameLabel, createDateLabel, yearLabel)]];
```

EDIT:

Ok, after implementing some suggestions:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(52)-[nameLabel]-[createDateLabel]-[yearLabel]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView, nameLabel, createDateLabel, yearLabel)]];
```

gives gets them all right aligned:

[image]

I would prefer to keep it pinned to the headerView so if that view changes height, I won't need to recode the pin space. Also, if I pin to headerView, it causes the labels to shift all the way to the right:

[image]

So that might just be a losing battle.

I still need to figure out how to pin them to the left and keep the ":" lined up. Right now, I pin createDateLabel because when I'm visually looking at it, I can see its the widest. Is there way I can get it to know which label will be the widest?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by :

1. Align trailing edges not leading
2. Pin leading space from superview to be >= [some const value]. This will make the labels have at least the given spacing from the left edge.
3. Pin the vertical spacing as you are

If you know which label will be the longest, you can also just pin that elements leading space to superview to your constant.

All of these constraints can be made in interface builder too, so that makes your life slightly easier

Comment: I did do as suggested, pined to parent view and it works. I would prefer it pined to the "headerView" incase if I change the height, everything else would move down instead of having to recode it. Any idea how to do this? I did do previous objects in IB, I didn't like it, its too temperamental (make one change and you can lose lots of other constraints).

Comment: The reason why it fails when you add `headerView` to the vertical constraint is that you are using `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing` When you add it to the same constraint that is constraining the labels, it will also align the right edge of the header with the right edge of the labels. To fix this, add a separate constraint that constrains the  vertical spacing between the headerview and the top label. You can do this in IB or with code

Comment: if you choose the code route, create an individual constraint that pins the top of one label to the bottom of the headerview with a constant that represents the spacing between, or use a visual constraint format that has no alignment specifications (option=0) that pins the top label to the headerview

Answer (score 1):

How about adding individual constraints to shorter labels:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *createDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    createDateLabel.text = @"Created date:";
    createDateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:createDateLabel];

    UILabel *yearLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    yearLabel.text = @"Year:";
    yearLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:yearLabel];

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nameLabel.text = @"Name:";
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:nameLabel];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[createDateLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(createDateLabel)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-40-[nameLabel]-[createDateLabel]-[yearLabel]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, createDateLabel, yearLabel)]];

    // skip these
    // [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nameLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:createDateLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    // [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yearLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:createDateLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```

and the output is this:

[image]

I agree it is easier to achieve it in IB, but if you are forced to do it in code..

Good reading is this: [Creating Individual Layout Constraints](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/02/20/creating-individual-layout-constraints/)

Comment: This answer will work as well, but it may be a little cleaner just to align the right edges instead of leading edges. That would eliminate the need for the other individual constraints

Comment: sorry I was not very clear. In the vertical constraint, you specify `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading` and then align the right edges individually. You can eliminate the second part by using `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing`

Comment: You're right, setting `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing` in the vertical constraint is the best solution. Must have been blind last night :)

Comment: Ok, I changed it from "constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[headerView]-[nameLabel]" to yours "constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-40-[nameLabel]" and it works. With pinning it to the [headerView], when I tried `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing` it placed them all on the right most edge of the parent view. I guess I liked pinning it to the [headerView] instead since if I changed the height of it, everything would move down accordingly. Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: I would then make constraints in 2 lines. One for your labels "V:[nameLabel]-[createDateLabel]-[yearLabel]" with `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing` and second between headerView and nameLabel: `[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nameLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];
`

Answer (score 0):

Make all the labels the same width (set a definite width constraint on all of them) and make their text alignment all be right-aligned.

Here's my rendering. No code - this was set up entirely using constraints in Interface Builder. The longest one ("Create Date:") is adopting its natural width; the others have the same width. All contain right-aligned text, obviously. Other needed constraints are obvious.

[image]

Comment: How can I make them all the same length if I don't know which one will be the widest label? I thought I could just try [nameLabel(==nameLabel)]-[createDateLabel(==nameLabel)], but I won't know which would be wider, nameLabel or createDateLabel.

Comment: Looks to me like the one that says "Created date:" is pretty obviously widest text by far! You could let it adopt its natural width, and set the width of the others to equal that.

Comment: Yes, looking at it we can see. What if I don't know ahead of time which will be the widest. Can I program it to handle that?

Comment: Certainly. What can be done in constraints in Interface Builder can be done in constraints generated and applied in code.

Comment: And what can be done "by looking" can be done in code, asking each label how wide it would like to be. The longest one is then the one that acts as the guide.